# When a batter reaches second safely after a rundown, does the batter get credited with a single or a double?

Tags: baseball, scoring

A batter hit a single toward right field, but instead of stopping at first, he rounded the base and - intentionally - caused a rundown (the player told me after the game he did this intentionally). He eventually reached second base safely. The defence committed no errors.

Should that be scored as a double?
Or should it be scored as a single with a stolen base?
Or should it be something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's a double. If you get a base hit and reach second on the play without any errors being made on the player it is scored as a [double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_(baseball)), assuming it was not on a [fielders choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fielder%27s_choice) (which is unlikely to allow you to reach second anyway, unless if there is an error).

Comment: It's probably up to the official scorer's judgement. If the defense wakes up in the middle of the rundown and sees a runner trying to score, they may stop the rundown and throw home. If the scorer believes that the runner would have otherwise been forced to return to first or tagged out, it would probably be scored as a single, with the runner advancing on the throw home.